# Extended child function can't use 'this', keyword not defined

Tags: javascript

My createCon function uses this to set the con for this object. I am getting this to be undefined. Error: Can not set property of 'con' of undefined. 
What is the best of being able to reference this from the objects functions?

```
class parent {
    constructor(stringA, stringB){
        this.config = {};
        this.con = {};
    }
}

class child extends parent {
    constructor(stringA, stringB) {
        super(stringA,stringB)
        this.config = {
            full : stringA+stringB
        }
    }

    createConn(){
        var con = con(this.config.full);
        con.connect(function(err){
            if(!err) this.con = con;
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan This is not a scope issue. It is a binding issue. The behaviour of `this` is specified separately from variable scopes.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `this` keyword inside of a `function`. `this` is not like other OOP languages and refers to a 'context', which can change based on the execution of the function.

You want to use an arrow function, which will lexically bind (i.e, preserve) the `this` of the context where the arrow function is defined.

```
createConn(){
    var con = con(this.config.full);
    con.connect((err) => {
        if(!err) this.con = con;
    })
}
```